# Updating Time on Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, web

This sounds like an easy problem but what is the best way to update server code to display date.
i have a website that on start up creates a list object, grabs date var using c# function then displays date and some content to user.
The next day the date being used is still the one from yesterday. My thinking so far is

1. i could set a schedule task to restart web application at mid night.
   not a big deal for my app, but data may be lost during restart ?
2. Add a function to check date and bind it to a button but it may be fired off more than necessary (only need once daily)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not considering using javascript for this?

Comment: Is this a static page that the user always has open and never causes a postback?  Why not have it grab the date on the page_load of whatever page you want this to display on so it updates everytime a user visits the page?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried up to this point?

Comment: yes i always have the page open and date is displayed on top right. If i refresh the page it is updated but i would prefere not to remember to do that everyday

Comment: If it must come from the server, you should use a timed ajax call.  This will not cause your page too refresh and then you can use javascript to update your field.